# parse mail to fetch attachments

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, email, parsing, mime

how do I parse a mail in Cocoa?
I've read the NSScanner tutorial, but struggled.
Do you know any better way than NSScanner?
Is there any sample code?

My example:

http://pastie.org/private/pordph27stkwkyvrx2tiq

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot find any cocoa libraries to do the job you need done, you can always use C++ or C libraries for your tasks. e.g. [Scaling Web's Parser](http://www.scalingweb.com/mime_parser.php). Apple has [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1) on how to use C++ from Objective C

Answer (score 1):

I use [C-Client](http://www.washington.edu/imap/). It's C only, a bit hard to understand but it gets the job done.

I wouldn't take on writing a MIME parser myself - it's lots of work if you look at the RFCs that come into play.